# C# TSQL How to perform an IF column reached SELECT INTO with current data copied over?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I perform a check using CASE to check if a specific column has been reached then SELECT INTO INSERT into a another table while copying the current data over into this second table?

This is because my first tbl cases only accepts inserts upto column 20 (in the real world these are actually upload files).

The two by definition are exactly the same as I populated the second from a Select Table As > Script into > New table query ....etc. ID is in both are identity cols.

For example:

--INSERT THE SAME DATA BUT DO NOT INSERT INTO COLUMN UploadNo1 to UploadNo20 into casesTwo as this should already have data (files from table cases).

```
   INSERT INTO casesTwo --ONLY FILE FROM COLUMN UploadNo20
   SELECT CAST(
         CASE 
              WHEN No20 = 'UploadNo20' 
                 THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
         END)
   FROM cases
```

Answer (score 0):

No way with CASE - you have to list the first 20 columns manually. You will need a dynamic query if you want to get columns dynamically.

Here is a sample:

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @ColumnsLits NVARCHAR(max);

-- Concatenate first 20 columns:
SELECT TOP 20
    @ColumnsLits = isnull(@ColumnsLits + ', ', '') + column_name
FROM 
    information_schema.columns
WHERE
    table_name = 'YourTable'
ORDER BY
    ordinal_position
OPTION
    (MAXDOP 1)

-- You can check column list:
-- SELECT @ColumnsLits

-- Build the query:
SET @DynamicSQL = N'SELECT ' + @ColumnsLits + N' FROM YourTable'

-- ... and run it:
EXEC (@DynamicSQL)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have an example I could try? I think the database design here is not the best but I believe in the real world the ideal scenario is to dynamically create new 'UploadNo' columns until I reach a limit of some sort (whether column number e.g. 100th column(UploadNo100) or data memory size e.g. (If total uploads size hits 100mb). If so then throw an exception and block further uploading.)) Blocking/exception is not so much of an issue as the frontend currently only has 40 upload buttons (ddls) so user can't physically choose e.g. 41st upload.

Comment: Sure - just added a sample.

Comment: Thanks. I've done this so far for testing puposes and it works:  DECLARE DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE ColumnsList NVARCHAR(max);

SELECT TOP 20 ColumnsList = isnull(@ColumnsList + ', ', '') + IOSupportURL20
  FROM [ViewpointDB].[dbo].[tbl_suppcorr]
  
  SELECT ColumnsList

Comment: But this doesn't work: DECLARE @ DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @ ColumnsList NVARCHAR(max);

SELECT TOP 20 @ ColumnsList = isnull(@ ColumnsList + ', ', '') + IOSupportURL21
  FROM [ViewpointDB].[dbo].[tbl_suppcorr] AS scT
 --SELECT @ ColumnsList
  WHERE scT.ID = [dbo].[tbl_suppcorr].ID
  OPTION
    (MAXDOP 1)

-- You can check column list:
SELECT @ ColumnsList

Comment: The error is: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "dbo.tbl_suppcorr.ID" could not be bound.

Comment: ?!?!? ... Sorry, I don't see how you expect the code in your comment to work ... the EXEC (@DynamicSQL) should do the stuff that seems you are attempting to do without a dynamic query which cannot happen =/